# Change name on JButtons in a JList within a scrollpane

Tags: java

I have a JFrame with a scrollpane and a JList. For some reason I can't rename these buttons and the originally set text is not there.

```
private DefaultListModel<JButton> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
private JList<JButton> emailList = new JList<>(model);
private JButton test = new JButton("test");
```

In constructor:

```
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
    scroll.getViewport().setView(emailList);
    scroll.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 350));
    add(scroll, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    model.addElement(test);
```

The name of this button ends up being

```
javax.swing.JButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@1de0aca6,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=testar,defaultCapable=true]
```

Comment: `toString()` method does not print the name of the button. To get the name, use `getName()`. That is, only if you used `setName("some name")`. If you only used the constructor, then you need to use `getText()` to get the text that is displayed in the GUI

Comment: I don't want to get the name, I want to set it to something other than that long line. setName() does not work

Comment: As I told you. `toString()` will never change, no matter what you set the text/name to

Comment: `JList` calls `toString`, which returns that annoyingly long name. If you want the name that you gave it, make an adaptor class whose `toString` does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Display text of `JList` items are derived by calling `toString()` on those items. `JButton.toString()` returns that long text "javax.swing.JButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid...". So, that's why you get that long text on `JList` items.

One way of solving this problem is by writing your own class extending `JButton` and overriding `toString()` in your class. Like in below example.

**NOTE:**

If you are expecting `JButton` functionality (e.g. clicking the button) from your list items, then you will have to do more than this. You will have to write a custom cell renderer and use it in your `JList`.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonList
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    CustomButton test = new CustomButton("test");
    CustomButton b2 = new CustomButton("button 2");
    CustomButton b3 = new CustomButton("button 3");
    DefaultListModel<CustomButton> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
    model.addElement(test);
    model.addElement(b2);
    model.addElement(b3);

    JList<CustomButton> emailList = new JList<>(model);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(emailList));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocation(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class CustomButton extends JButton
{
  CustomButton(String text)
  {
    super(text);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return getText();
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I would argue for [composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) here. We're not making a *new type* of button; we're making a new way of looking at ordinary everyday buttons.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it in a bit